# jquery select2: no matches found

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

When I set the select2 (3.4.0) value with the following code:

```
el.select2('val', [1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]);
```

it shows me the `no matches found` message. It happens only at start-up, if I put focus on select2 popup menu the message dissapears and never appears again...

[image]

How can I remove this message? Thank you

Comment: would this help : https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/448

Comment: @karthikr this is something else.. I don't want to handle event or format message..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue where 'No matches found' was showing. Turns out I forgot to update the CSS when I updated my javascript to 3.4.0. Check to make sure you didn't make the same mistake.